# jQuery: jScrollHorizontalPane - Adding content dynamically

Tags: jquery

I have a set of images in a jScrollHorizontalPane and I want to be able to change the content of the pane per project.

Currently this is what I have loading every time a project is selected:

```
    $.each(project.images || [], function()
{
    if(this == "") return;
    imgCont.append('<div class="image-item"><img height="225" src="' + this + '" /></div>');
});
var width = 0;
imgCont.find('img').each(function()
{
    width += $(this).width();
});
imgCont.width(width);
$('#project-images-scroll').jScrollHorizontalPane (
    {
        scrollbarHeight:10, 
        scrollbarMargin:0,
        reset:true,
        animateTo:false,
        animateInterval:25,
        animateStep:5
    }
);
```

But what ends up happening is the scroll bar is reset but not working when clicked.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: is the element with id `#project-images-scroll` generated dynamically?

Comment: No, it in the dom the whole time, should I recreate it every time?

Answer (score 0):

The way to fix this was by cloning the entire tree of the scroller. Then on each instance of changing content the entire tree should be `.remove()` 'd and reinitialized from a clone of the clone.